# What password to use to log in after the first boot?

Tags: setup, boot, password

The first time I boot up my Raspberry Pi I get a login screen.

What username and password should I use?  That is, what is the default password for Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Distribution dependent.

Comment: Of course ... but still well worth answering. :)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This depends on the distribution you have downloaded. The default passwords for common distributions are as follows:

```
Distribution   | Username   | Password
---------------|------------|-------------
Debian Squeeze | pi         | raspberry
Arch           | root       | root
QtonPi         | root       | rootme
Raspbian       | pi         | raspberry
OpenElec       | root       | openelec
```

Straight after logging in you should **change** your password by using the *passwd* command at the shell prompt

```
$ passwd
```

Comment: +1 Recommending that users should change their password. Especially since these passwords are available on the Raps Pi site, in plain text

Comment: [NOOBS](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs) also includes [Pidora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#History_2), [RISC OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC_OS), and [RaspBMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_based_on_XBMC#Raspbmc). Those could be included for completeness.

Comment: Keep in mind that the keyboard layout used by you Raspberry Pi could be a different one than the one you are used to! US Layout: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBjUk.jpg)

Comment: LibreElec | root | libreelec

Comment: Note that Raspbian after April 2022 has no default user any more!

Answer (score 14):

```
Distribution   | Username   | Password
---------------|------------|-------------
Debian Squeeze | pi         | raspberry
Arch           | root       | root
QtonPi         | root       | rootme
Raspbian       | pi         | raspberry
OpenElec       | root       | openelec
Pidora         | root       | raspberrypi
RISC OS        | n/a        | n/a
raspbmc        | pi         | raspberry
```

Comment: LibreElec | root | libreelec

Answer (score 6):

Beware if you are using a German keyboard: In this case you have to use pi / raspberrz

Comment: Why would this be the case?

Comment: German keyboards have the Z and Y key swapped: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout

Comment: Yes but surely if you press the Y key, the keyboard is going to send a piece of data to the Pi saying that the Y key has been pressed? Under what circumstances would that not occur?

Comment: Keyboard drivers sometimes use keycodes relative to the location of the button and not the letter printed on top of it.

Comment: I used to have the problem with DOS based games a lot back in the old days.

Comment: @DarthVader: The keyboard tells the pi that key "row 2, column 7" was pressed. The Pi translates this to "Y". With a German keyboard, the Y key is at row 4, column 3, and the Pi doesn't know this is supposed to be an Y. (I'm oversimplifying a bit, google for "scancode" - you need to send the Pi the scancode that corresponds to Y, which is the Z on a German keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

With Raspbian, the username is `pi`, and the password is `raspberry`. You can change the password by running the command `passwd`, using the `raspi-config` tool, or the graphical `Raspberry Pi Configuration` tool. On Arch, the username is `root` and the password is `root`. You can also change the password with the command `passwd`.

Answer (score 0):

With Raspbian, the username is `pi` and the password is `raspberry`.
Also note that SSH is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers about 'Beware if you are using a German keyboard: In this case you have to use pi / raspberrz', they are omitting to say that this is an issue after first boot because the user cannot yet have told the pi that a German keyboard is attached. The pi defaults to expecting a UK English keyboard. Once that's changed, all the letters and symbols will be correct.

The same issue also applies for other language keyboards - eg symbols in the wrong places - until the correct language driver is installed (eg, using sudo raspi-config). But it matters most for the password because the default contains a 'y' and needs the 7th key along on 2nd row (which is marked Y on the default English and many other keyboards but Z on a German keyboard).

Users with French 'AZERTY' keyboards will have to substitute for the 'A' in raspberry (press the 2nd key on 3rd row, whatever it is marked ...)

Answer (score 0):

With dietpi it would be root/dietpi or dietpi/dietpi.

Comment: 9years ago there was no DietPi. If I remember right, the first release was around 2013.

Answer (score 0):

For Razberry z-wave it's:
razberry

Answer (score 0):

With Raspberry pi OS (previously called Raspbian) release of April 2022, the default user and password was removed, making it impossible to login via uart directly after installation for instance. It is necessary to login via the graphical UI and to create a user account there first. See https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/