# How can I change the Raspberry Pi user password?

Tags: debian, setup, password

I will be needing to access my Raspberry Pi while I am away from home, and [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) would be good for this purpose. I am using it with password authentication, and I don't want to mess around with SSH keys.

However, I don't want people to access the server using the default password, so I need to change the Raspberry Pi user password from "raspberry" to something else.

Comment: SSH keys are really very easy and much more secure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the password of the current user by running `passwd`.

#### Related Questions

1. [How do I create a new user?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/487/86)
2. [What password to use to log in after the first boot?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/660/86)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the raspi-config script. So run:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

A menu will pop up that allows a bunch of things, but if you look at the 4th thing down, select change_pass

```
change_pass        Change password for 'pi' user
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo passwd pi` for no prompt for current password, `passwd` for standard change. You can also use the graphical configuration tool or `sudo raspi-config` to change it, if you are using the default `pi` user.